# What is the persistent model of garlik 4store

Tags: database, rdf, triplestore, 4store

I need to know how 4store make the persistence of it's triples in the database, if it's like a table of 3 columns, one for each element in the triple or if it's another way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's somewhat more complex than that, but it's described in this whitepaper:
http://4store.org/publications/harris-ssws09.pdf

There's a number of indexes, 2 are tables of 4 elements, indexed by a Patricia Trie (the quadstore part), one is an index from graph IDs to lists of triples (the triplestore part).

There's also a distributed hash, which holds URIs and so on.